# Yammer and Distribution Groups - notifications

Tags: office365, yammer

In our organization we have an office 365, in which we have created the alias all@example.com as a distribution list. Here a problem arises because Yammer sends notifications to each user separately (name@example.com) and to all@example.com, which duplicates the message. How do I delete the "all" alias from Yammer notifications? Of course, in the Yammer settings in the "remove users" tab, there is no such distribution group. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm better suited to answer questions about developing against Yammer's APIs. If you read my response and are still having trouble, you should probably contact Office365 or your Microsoft rep.

Any email address that is receiving email notifications from Yammer is probably signed up for Yammer. Are you sure it's not there? If not, the other thing to check might be any weird configurations with an Outlook group that is mapped (or incorrectly mapped) to a Yammer group. Perhaps this is where the notifications are coming from.